# How I can get the plain-text source of a web page that I've generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html

I want to know how I can get the plain-text source code of a web page that I've generated dynamically with JavaScript.

---

1. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to see the **updated** html structure of my page's as it appears when viewing the page's original source code.
2. I know that I can go into dev tools and look at the page's current html structure in detail, but that is a mess to weave through, having to open each and every div on the page.

---

I'd like to be able to see a plain text HTML representation of the page *including* content **generated after page load** with JavaScript.

Comment: that's the magic word bro...:)

Comment: @rockStar Ah, but the magic word is `sudo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use outerHTML on the document element:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML; // entire source
```

This will give you a snapshot of the HTML source at the moment of the call. If you call it after the dynamic content is added you'll get the updated content.

<strike>While `outerHTML` is not a part of the DOM specification, de-facto all browsers support it</strike>

Update, I double checked, outerHTML is now a part of [the living standard here](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#outerhtml). Moreover, it is supported in all browsers.

Comment: Three answers provided: 2 people who didn't even read the question, and then this one, spot on. Thank you man